# What is Creator in Java and how to Translate it to C#

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am translating a code from Java to C#/Xamarin, but i am unable to understand the below mentioned code

```
public static class GraphicPath implements Parcelable
{
    protected GraphicPath(Parcel par)
    {
        int size=in.readInt();
        int[] x=new int[size];
        int[] y=new int[size];
        in.readIntArray(x);
        in.readIntArray(y);
        pathX=new ArrayList<>();
        pathY=new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            pathX.add(x[i]);
        }

        for (int i=0;i<y.length;i++){
            pathY.add(y[i]);
        }
    }

    //Unable to understand and translate the below code.
    public static final Creator<GraphicPath> CREATOR = new Creator<GraphicPath>() {
       @Override
        public GraphicPath createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new GraphicPath(in);
        }

        @Override
        public GraphicPath[] newArray(int size) {
            return new GraphicPath[size];
        }
   };
}
```

what is it and how to convert it to C#, and how to translate the Java handler code to C# ? is handler a thread ? how to convert the below handlers to C#

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

 new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startCapture();
                }
            },1000);

handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                toCapture();
            }
        });
        return;
```

The converted C# code gives error, the C# code implements IParcelable interface and it doesn't have Creator in it.

```
 public class GraphicPath : IParcelable
{
    protected GraphicPath(Parcel par)
    {
        int size =par.ReadInt();
        int[] x = new int[size];
        int[] y = new int[size];
        par.ReadIntArray(x);
        par.ReadIntArray(y);
        pathX = new List<int>();
        pathY = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            pathX.Add(x[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < y.Length; i++)
        {
            pathY.Add(y[i]);
        }
    }

    //Red lines here
    public static Creator<GraphicPath> CREATOR = new Creator<GraphicPath>() {

        //paste here
    };
  }
```

Comment: Add your `includes` to your question just to make sure it is `Parcelable.Creator` Also if you are porting Android Java to Xamarin C#, you are aware of: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.OS.Handler/

Comment: IParcelable is an interface in xamarin c# and it doesn't have Creator in it

Comment: So you didn't find: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.OS.Parcelable/

Comment: Look at how this person is doing it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41582330/why-is-my-parcelable-creator-not-working

Comment: @Sweeper thankyou, it helped, anything about handlers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've done this in my port of `ViewPagerIndicator` for saving state: https://github.com/Cheesebaron/ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/Library/CirclePageIndicator.cs#L535

So to create your own creator you would do:

```
public class GraphicPathCreator : Java.Lang.Object, IParacleableCreator
{
    public Java.Lang.Object CreateFromParcel(Parcel source)
    {
        return new GraphicPath(source);
    }

    public Java.Lang.Object[] NewArray(int size)
    {
        return new GraphicPath[size];
    }
}
```

Then you can define the `CREATOR` like:

```
[ExportField("CREATOR")]
public static GraphicPathCreator Creator()
{
    return new GraphicPathCreator();
}
```

The `ExportField` here is important. It exposes your method as `CREATOR` in the Android Callable Wrappers.

To combine this with your `GrapicPath` it would look something like:

```
public static class GraphicPath : BaseSavedState
{
    public List<int> PathX { get; private set; }
    public List<int> PathY { get; private set; }

    public GraphicPath(IParcelable superState)
        : base(superState)
    {
    }

    public GraphicPath(Parcel parcel) : base(parcel)
    {
        var size = parcel.ReadInt();
        int[] x = new int[size];
        int[] y = new int[size];
        parcel.ReadIntArray(x);
        parcel.ReadIntArray(y);
        PathX = new List<int>(x);
        PathY = new List<int>(y);
    }

    public override void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, ParcelableWriteFlags flags)
    {
        base.WriteToParcel(dest, flags);
        dest.WriteInt(PathX.Count);
        dest.WriteIntArray(PathX.ToArray());
        dest.WriteIntArray(PathY.ToArray());
    }

    // creator stuff here
```

As for `Handlers` there are a couple of ways to tackle those. You can convert them to C# Task's or keep them as is and just translate them 1:1.

For the 1:1 conversion they would look like:

```
var handler = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper);
handler.PostDelayed(() => StartCapture(), 1000);

handler.Post(() => ToCapture());
```

The lambdas are just anonymous instances of `Action`.

Answer (score 0):

Creator is used for the Parcelable, Parcelable is used for serializing of class to pass them between activities via Intents, so you have to follow this documentation https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.OS.Parcelable/
 how to use them in Xamarin

```
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
     private int mData;

     public int describeContents() {
         return 0;
     }

     public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
         out.writeInt(mData);
     }

     public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
             = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
         public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
             return new MyParcelable(in);
         }

         public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
             return new MyParcelable[size];
         }
     };

     private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
         mData = in.readInt();
     }
 }
```

also for the handler you have to check this documentation https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.OS.Handler/

Comment: This Java code does not compile unless you do it through a binding library. There are no `final` or `implements` keywords in C#.

Comment: @Cheesebaron are so you saying that the documenation is wrong? not expert in Xamarin but I remember you can write code for specific Android while coding in Xamarin, so you can have there your Parcelable part

Comment: The docs are just a mirror of the Android counterpart. You cannot just put this directly in a Xamarin app.

Comment: i cannot test it, so whatever